# How to make a dynamic 'where' query to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My collection "abc" looks like this:

```
abc
  doc1: {
    users: {
      uid1: {
        gender: 'm',
        age: '99'
      },
      uid2: ...
      uid3: ...
      ...
    }
  },
  doc2: {
    ...
```

Now I want to find all docs that have a certain uid key in users. (I'm querying from inside a cloud function)

```
const uid = context.params.uid
```

I tried the following queries:

```
db.collection('abc').where(`users[${uid}]`, '>', '').get()
db.collection('abc').where(`users.${uid}`, '>', '').get()
db.collection('abc').where(`users[${uid}].gender`, '>', '').get()
db.collection('abc').where(`users.${uid}.gender`, '>', '').get()
```

They will cause an error in the functions console saying it's not a valid field path. So I also tried these

```
db.collection('abc').where(new admin.firestore.FieldPath(`users[${uid}]`), '>', '').get()
db.collection('abc').where(new admin.firestore.FieldPath(`users[${uid}].gender`), '>','').get()
db.collection('abc').where(new admin.firestore.FieldPath(`users.${uid}`), '>', '').get()
db.collection('abc').where(new admin.firestore.FieldPath(`users.${uid}.gender`), '>', '').get()
```

Which also failed.

So does that mean a dynamic where query is not possible? Or how do I do this correctly? Should I structure my data differently? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sample just seems syntactically broken:

```
db.collection('abc').where(`users[${uid}]`, '>', '').get()
```

I think you're looking for:

```
db.collection('abc').where('users.' + uid, '>', '').get()
```

Firestore has fairly [limited support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#nested_data_in_documents) in dealing with repeated nested values inside a document. While it *is* possible to model a map like what you have, you might want to look at some alternative data models.

---

If you want to be able to query for documents that contain a certain UID, I'd recommend adding an array field with just the UIDs to your data structure:

```
doc1: {
  uids: ['uid1', 'uid2', 'uid3']
}
```

Now you can [use the `array-contains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to find all documents that are associated with a certain UID.

```
db.collection('abc').where('uids', 'array-contains', 'uid1')
```

---

You could do the same for all fields where you want to do an equality check. You're essentially turning the associate array you have into multiple mathematical sets.

---

If you want to perform range queries, like you're trying to do on the age, you will have to store the users in a subcollection for each document.

```
abc // collection
  doc1: { // document
    users: { // collection
      uid1: { // document
        gender: 'm',
        age: '99'
      },
      uid2:  // document
      uid3:  // document
      ...
    }
  },
  doc2: { // document
    ...
```

With this structure you can then query on the subcollection (or across all `users` subcollections), which allows range queries again (as `age` at that point is not a repeated field).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So doing it with a where query is definitely not possible? Then I will go with your approach. Restructuring to an array of maps 

`users: [ { uid: abc, gender: m, age: 99 } ]`


is probably also not good, because of problems querying that?

Comment: I added some more on the first problem you have at the top of my answer.

Comment: I have been using dynamic paths in 'update()', so I assumed they work with 'where()', too...

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I do not plan to use range queries on the age field. I only included 'age' in my queries as i thought maybe the '>' only works with strings/numbers, but not maps. I will implement it as you wrote! 